# How to handle Docker login to Gitlab container registry with multiple concurrent jobs?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

We use Gitlab CI/CD, building and deploying with runners on locally hosted machines and using the Gitlab container registry to store our Docker images. We log in to the Gitlab registry like so:

```yaml
default:
  before_script:
    - "docker login -u \"${CI_REGISTRY_USER}\" -p \"${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}\" \"${CI_REGISTRY}\""
```

This works fine with the runners in our deployment environments, which each only run a single job concurrently. However, our build machine is supposed to run multiple build jobs concurrently. The problem is, the `${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}` provided by Gitlab for each job is different and, it seems, valid only for that job. Thus, when we have multiple jobs running at once, their calls to `docker login` overwrite each other, causing other jobs to fail with `authentication required` errors.

Currently, we're working around the problem by performing a new `docker login` command before every `docker push` or `docker pull` to minimize the chance that another job will perform a login command of its own in between, but there's got to be a better way.

What is the recommended solution for managing Docker registry logins with concurrent jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing is best handled using a Deploy Token, it's exactly what it was intended for. This allows you to set a user, so you can tell the CI server was the one who pushed the container, and also set expiration for security reasons:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/

Comment: I thought about it and should probably clarify, you'd want to set this as a secret under settings -> CI/CD -> Variables (make sure it's set to masked so it doesn't display in logs)

I am a little confused on a few things, namely why your CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD variable is different for each job, and how you have your runner set up so as docker login is overwriting the config file.

Comment: One other way to go about it is just put a check in place, and only run docker-login if the config file isn't there:

if [ ! -d ~/.docker ];then docker login {{ LOGIN STRING }};fi

Comment: A deploy token is exactly what we ended up using. I didn't end up integrating it into the CI/CD pipeline at all; I just manually did `docker login` once on each machine and as long as no other logins were performed, it would stay valid. I don't know why the password was changing - in fact, it was an assumption that that was the case. All I know is that if one pipeline did a login, then another did a login, then the first did a push or pull, the push or pull would fail.